# Dataframe updates with pandas that includes duplicated column headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am incredibly new to pandas python module and have a problem I'm trying to solve. Take the following dataframe as an example. This was read in from a .csv where "link" is the column header for the last three columns:

```
  summary       link     link.1     link.2
0    test  PCR-12345  PCR-54321  PCR-65432
1   test2        NaN        NaN        NaN
2   test3    DR-1234   PCR-1244        NaN
3   test4   PCR-4321    DR-4321        NaN
```

My goal is to update the dataframe to the following:

```
  summary       link     link.1     link.2
0    test        NaN        NaN        NaN
1   test2        NaN        NaN        NaN
2   test3    DR-1234        NaN        NaN
3   test4        NaN    DR-4321        NaN
```

So the criteria is basically, if the column header is "link.X" AND the value contains a string that starts with "PCR-", update it to an empty/NaN value.

How do I loop through each row's values, check the header and value, and replace if criteria is satisfied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used @Quang Hoang's answer. I also need to make sure the headers were written back out to a csv as their original values. I did that by first doing this to grab the original header:

```
with open('test.csv') as f:
        orig_header = f.readline()
orig_header = orig_header.split (",")
orig_header[-1] = orig_header[-1].strip() #get rid of newline
```

I then went ahead and did the data manipulation with Quang's sugeestion. After that I write it back out to a csv with the original header:

```
df.to_csv('test_updated.csv', index = False, header=orig_header)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's try [`pd.Series.str.startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) and [`pd.Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
# columns starting with `link`
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str[:4]=='link']

# for each `link` column, mask the `PCR` with `NaN`:
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.mask(x.str.startswith('PCR')==True) )
```

Output:

```
  summary     link   link.1 link.2
0    test      NaN      NaN    NaN
1   test2      NaN      NaN    NaN
2   test3  DR-1234      NaN    NaN
3   test4      NaN  DR-4321    NaN
```

Comment: what does the `:4` do in `str[:4]`?

Comment: extracts the first 4 characters from each element inside the column names.

Comment: `df.columns.str[:4]=='link'` is essentially equivalent to `df.columns.str.startswith('link')` since `len('link')==4`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way. uses `str.startswith()` to find the columns that start with `link`, then `where()` to keep only the cases that are true.:

```
cols = df.columns.str.startswith('link')
df.loc[:,cols] = df.loc[:,cols].where(df.loc[:,cols].replace(r'[-].*','',regex=True).eq('DR'))
```